# Math.pow(7,5) is not the same as 7*7*7*7*7 -- Why?

Tags: java

While doing a simple PRNG project. I came across strange behavior of Math.pow and simply multiplying the numbers together. What is the cause of this? I've included the PRNG class, along with the main class I used to run the program. If you compare the results, it starts nicely, but on the 3rd iteration, the multiplicative PRNG diverges from the Math.pow() PRNG. The multiplicative PRNG also starts giving negative numbers. Which it shouldn't.

```
public class PRNG {
int seed;
/**
 * Creates a PRNG with the seed x0
 */
public PRNG(int x0){
    this.seed = x0;
}

/**
 * Return the next random number
 */
public int nextRand(){
    //seed = (int) ((Math.pow(7, 5) * seed) % (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1));
    seed = (int) ((7*7*7*7*7 * seed) % (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1));
    return seed;
}
```

}

main:

```
public class main {
final static int SEED = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PRNG prng = new PRNG(SEED);     

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        System.out.println(prng.nextRand());
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you seeing that `Math.pow(7, 5)` is different than `7*7*7*7*7`?

Comment: Yes, it's  the same result , but you must remember that `pow` method return `double` type, that cause the result could be truncated when you treat as integer.

Comment: When you compare the output. With 100 iterations, you can see the first couple prngs generated are the same, but then they diverge.

Comment: Also, `Math.pow(2,31)` could just be `1 << 31`.

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind, the seed is in fact changing. I take it back. It's  simple integer overflow.

Comment: Using pow and % are very expensive and you can write your code without using either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you are overflowing the INT value of seed.

Changing your code to this:

```
seed = (int) ((7*7*7*7*7 * (long)seed) % (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1));
```

Fixes the problem.

Comment: Ah! But why does the seed not overflow when using Math.pow()?

Comment: Math.pow returns a double which has more precision than int.

Comment: Doh! That makes perfect sense. Thank you :)

Comment: @gnunaes It overflows differently. `7*7*7*7*7*seed` will overflow by taking mod 2^32 (aside from the sign). `Math.pow()` will return a number greater than `2^31 - 1` which will probably cast down to `2^31 - 1`.

Comment: I suggest `seed = (int) ((7*7*7*7*7 * (long)seed) % ((1<<31) - 1));` to avoid overhead with double calculus. I suppose the compiler resolve `((1<<31) - 1)` and replace it by the constant 7FFFFFFF.

Comment: @Aubin Thanks! I will. I was trying to find a way to avoid Math.pow, and that's how I ran into this problem.

Comment: +1, but slight nit to your comment, @dkatzel. It's true that `double` has more precision than `int`, but its real strength here is that it has a much bigger _range_. A `double` can also express numbers _much_ larger than a `long` can, despite having lower precision.

Comment: @yshavit yes you are right, I misspoke when I said precision, I meant larger range.

Answer (score 0):

To address the title of your question, there is no difference.

```
public class MathPow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testInt();
        testLong();
    }

    private static void testInt(){
        int a = 7*7*7*7*7;
        int b = (int) Math.pow(7,5);
        System.out.printf("a=%d b=%d (a==b)=%b\n", a, b, a==b);
    }
    private static void testLong(){
        long a = 7*7*7*7*7;
        long b = (long) Math.pow(7,5);
        System.out.printf("a=%d b=%d (a==b)=%b\n", a, b, a==b);
    }
}
```

Produces the output:

```
a=16807 b=16807 (a==b)=true
a=16807 b=16807 (a==b)=true
```

Comment: -1, you have showed that `7*7*7*7*7` is the same as `(int) Math.pow(7,5)`. Not that `7*7*7*7*7` is the same as `Math.pow(7,5)`.

Comment: If you did this with `7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7`, and `(int)Math.pow(7, 20)` you would not get the same answer.

Comment: I showed that they are numerically equivalent.  He didn't ask about 7^20.

Comment: The point is, that you're showing that they're equivalent AFTER some conversion(casting). If you have to convert, then they simply aren't equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

To address the behavior you're concerned with rather than the title of your post:

Steps of evaluation:

```
seed = (int) ((Math.pow(7, 5) * seed) % (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1));
```

- Math.pow(7, 5) = double (16807)
- double * int = double (64-bit)
- Math.pow(2,31) = double
- double - int = double
- double % double = double
- double gets cast to int

`seed = (int) ((7*7*7*7*7 * seed) % (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1));`

- 7*7*7*7*7 = int (16807)
- int * int = int  // It overflows the value of integer here.
- Math.pow(2,31) = double
- double - int = double
- int % double = double
- double gets cast to int

To demonstrate:

```
public class MathPow {
    static int seed=1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("7*7*7*7*7");
        whatType(7*7*7*7*7);
        whatType(7*7*7*7*7*seed);
        whatType(Math.pow(2,31));
        whatType(Math.pow(2,31)-1);
        whatType(((7*7*7*7*7 * seed) % (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1)));

        System.out.println("Math.pow(7,5)");
        whatType(Math.pow(7,5));
        whatType(Math.pow(7,5) * seed);
        whatType(Math.pow(2,31));
        whatType(Math.pow(2,31)-1);
        whatType((Math.pow(7, 5) * seed) % (Math.pow(2, 31) - 1));

    }
    private static void whatType(Object o){
        System.out.println(o.getClass());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
7*7*7*7*7
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.Double
Math.pow(7,5)
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.Double
```